# Как подключить Sass к HTML5 boilerplate?

Tags: html5, gulp-sass

Как подключить Sass к HTML5 boilerplate ?Таск менеджер gulp. Желательно детальное описание так как новичок.

Comment: Думаю вам надо подключить boilerplate к sass. Точнее подключить sass в gulp, и в главный файл импортить css boilerplate.

Comment: @ArtemGorlachev я просто хочу не только css а весь шаблон и что бы в нём можно было использовать Sass